# ¿Se utiliza la palabra "esplín"? ¿Cómo de común o frecuente es su uso?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, palabras-raras

El [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GdQZwXP) recoge **esplín** como:

> Del ingl. *spleen* 'bazo', 'melancolía', este del lat. *splen*, y este del gr. *σπλήν splḗn*.
>
> 1. m. Melancolía, tedio de la vida.

Y está incluido desde el diccionario de 1884 (con una definición prácticamente idéntica: "humor tétrico que produce tedio de la vida").

El **CREA** de la RAE apenas recoge 8 menciones, entre 1977 y 1997. El [**CDH**](http://web.frl.es/CNDHE/org/publico/pages/consulta/entradaCompleja.view) recoge 59 casos en 37 documentos, desde una obra teatral española anónima de 1769 hasta un periódico nicaragüense de 1997, pero la mayoría de las citas son anteriores a 1940.
[**Google Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=espl%C3%ADn%2Csicofanta&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cespl%C3%ADn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csicofanta%3B%2Cc0) recoge una frecuencia baja de la palabra, pero superior a, por ejemplo, *sicofanta*.

Parece, por tanto, que es una "palabra rara" — yo tan solo la he encontrado un par de veces en textos de los años sesenta, pero en España nunca la he oído y ninguno de mis conocidos la conoce. ¿Ocurre lo mismo en otras regiones hispanoparlantes?

Comment: Según el [NTLLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), el término "esplin" aparece en 1825 en el diccionario de Núñez de Taboada como "estado de consuncion externa", y en el diccionario de la academia de 1843 con la misma definición que comentas de 1884, y añade: "es voz tomada del inglés". En inglés tiene el significado arcaico de "melancolía". Tiene pinta de ser un anglicismo (igual que "fútbol") que no se llegó a imponer sobre otros términos que ya existían en nuestro idioma y que cubrían la misma definición.

Comment: It is archaic in English (apart from the organ obviously).

Comment: Aún más antiguo de lo que pensaba! Sobre su orígen inglés, el DRAE actual lo sigue recogíendolo ("Del ingl. spleen 'bazo', 'melancolía' ...). Lo que más me llama la atención es que, aunque poco, se siga utilizando, y que el DRAE no la califique de desusada, obsoleta o la haya eliminado.

Comment: El [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=espl%C3%ADn) sí que califica a la palabra como "de poco uso en la actualidad".

Comment: No es muy común, pero supongo que a muchos nos suena por el título del libro de Charles Baudelaire: [_El esplín de París_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peque%C3%B1os_poemas_en_prosa). En el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) se puede ver que en 1817 no estaba y en 1884 ya sí. El libro se publicó en 1869.

Comment: Ya no se usa, pero aparece en muchos tangos. Mi abuela (1914-1999) la usaba. Aparece también en la famosa poesía de Juan de Dios Peza “Reir llorando”.

Comment: En España, en mis 34 años no la he leído ni escuchado. Puede ser un arcaismo. Quizá en otras zonas de habla Hispana sí se use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Esplín", por supuesto, no es más que la españolización de la palabra [*spleen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spleen). Tengo la impresión de que estuvo de moda hace aproximadamente un siglo, sobre todo en Inglaterra y Francia, como herencia de la poesía romántica (hay, por ejemplo, un [poema](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/charles_baudelaire/spleen_je_suis_comme_le_roi_d_un_pays_pluvieux.html) célebre de Baudelaire), y así ingresó en el habla común, por el lado literario (parecidamente a como "estrés" —*stress*— vino del lado psicológico).

La cultura de mi país, Argentina, siempre (especialmente hace un siglo) tuvo mucha influencia francesa, y adivino que por eso mismo la palabra tuvo bastante uso (tanto "esplín" como *spleen*). Pero hoy se considera anticuada o literaria, y dudo que los más jóvenes la conozcan.

Algunos ejemplos —poéticos— que me vienen a la memoria:

- [*Reír llorando*](https://letransfusion.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/reir-llorando-garrick-juan-de-dios-peza/), poema/recitado de Juan de Dios Peza (México, ca. 1880).
- [*Canción de carnaval*](http://www.damisela.com/literatura/pais/nicaragua/autores/dario/profanas/carnaval_p3.htm), poema de Ruben Darío (Nicaragua, 1908).
- [*El solterón*](http://www.poesi.as/ll051290.htm), poema de Leopoldo Lugones (Argentina, 1909).
- [*Viejo ciego*](http://www.todotango.com/musica/tema/371/Viejo-ciego/), tango con letra de Catulo Castillo (Argentina, 1926).
- [*Balada para mi muerte*](http://www.todotango.com/musica/tema/174/Balada-para-mi-muerte/), tango con letra de Horacio Ferrer (Argentina, 1972).

Comment: Agrego _Mi noche triste_, tango de Pascual Contursi: "Percanta que me amuraste en lo mejor de mi vida, dejándome el alma herida y esplín en el corazón", aunque en muchos lugares figura _espina_ en vez de _esplín_.

Comment: Dos ejemplos más: Salvador Sanfuentes: _El campanario. Leyenda nacional en tres actos_ (1842): "Así, evitando que mi **esplin** se exhale en duras voces, a pintar me escurro"  y José Zorrilla (1844) en _Recuerdos y fantasías_ : "Un puro y una botella Durante mi **esplin**  consumo, Y cuando acabo con ella Cigarro y pesar son humo. Los vapores de los dos El cerebro me revuelven, Y me vuelven Tan feliz que ¡vive Dios! Esta vida larga ó corta, Poco me importa."